# Extract from last element of a list to a certain string

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need help to achieve this:

```
list_char = ['a','b','c','s','a','d','g','b','e']
```

I need this output:

```
['s','a','d','g','b','e']
```

So starting from the last element until the first 's' found (I can have more 's' before, so I have to start from the last element)

Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: @wnnmaw: nope, this is about an index search from the end, not about slicing.

Comment: Is your input always a list of *single* characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> list_char = ['a','b','c','s','a','d','g','b','e']
>>> list_char[-list_char[::-1].index('s')-1:]
['s', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the list to a string and then convert back:

```
In [83]: l = ['a','b','c','s','a','d','g','b','e']

In [85]: s=''.join(l)

In [87]: list(s[s.rfind('s'):])
Out[87]: ['s', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e']
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Is it possible to do only using the list comprehension notation?

Comment: @TheCondor wim has offered that

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with numpy, since it allows for easy manipulation.

```
list_char = ['a','b','c','s','a','d','g','b','e']
test = np.array(list_char)
```

This gives us an array of the strings, and now we need to find the last s in the array,

```
ind = np.where(test=='s')[-1]
#returns 3 in this cause, but would return the last index of s
```

Then slice

```
test[ind:]
#prints array(['s', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e'], dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list_char = ['a','b','c','s','a','d','g','b','e']
index = "".join(list_char).rindex('s')
print list_char[index:]
```